# Xamarin forms: Plugin.LatestVersion.LatestVersionException: Error comparing current app version number with latest

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting the below exception from the `Xam.Plugin.LatestVersion` plugin on my xamarin forms app:

> Plugin.LatestVersion.LatestVersionException: Error comparing current app version number with latest.

I found the same issue reported over [here](https://github.com/edsnider/latestversionplugin/issues/43) and [here](https://github.com/edsnider/latestversionplugin/issues/5) on GitHub. Also, the same issue is reported on the [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407251/how-to-get-version-number-of-application-from-play-store-using-xamarin-forms). I tried the solutions suggested on the above thread, but no luck.

I have updated my plugin version to the latest(2.1.0), but the same exception is showing. Any solution for this issue? The issue is only on the Android platform.

**Update:**

I have tried the 2.1.1-beta.107 version, now getting another exception.

> Plugin.LatestVersion.LatestVersionException: Error parsing content from the Play Store. Url=play store url&hl=en. ---> Jurassic.JavaScriptException: TypeError: undefined cannot be converted to an object
> at Jurassic.TypeConverter.ToObject (Jurassic.ScriptEngine engine, System.Object value, System.Int32 lineNumber, System.String sourcePath, System.String functionName) [0x00037] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at (wrapper dynamic-method) Jurassic.Compiler.MethodGenerator.anonymous(Jurassic.Compiler.ExecutionContext,object[])
> at Jurassic.Library.UserDefinedFunction.CallLateBound (System.Object thisObject, System.Object[] argumentValues) [0x00014] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at Jurassic.Library.FunctionInstance.CallWithStackTrace (System.String path, System.String function, System.Int32 line, System.Object thisObject, System.Object[] argumentValues) [0x0000f] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at (wrapper dynamic-method) Jurassic.Compiler.MethodGenerator.anonymous(Jurassic.Compiler.ExecutionContext,object[])
> at Jurassic.Library.UserDefinedFunction.CallLateBound (System.Object thisObject, System.Object[] argumentValues) [0x00014] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at Jurassic.Library.FunctionInstance.CallWithStackTrace (System.String path, System.String function, System.Int32 line, System.Object thisObject, System.Object[] argumentValues) [0x0000f] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at (wrapper dynamic-method) Jurassic.Compiler.MethodGenerator.eval(Jurassic.Compiler.ExecutionContext)
> at Jurassic.Compiler.GlobalOrEvalMethodGenerator.Execute (Jurassic.ScriptEngine engine, Jurassic.Compiler.RuntimeScope parentScope, System.Object thisObject) [0x00030] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at Jurassic.ScriptEngine.Evaluate (Jurassic.ScriptSource source) [0x000a7] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at Jurassic.ScriptEngine.Evaluate (System.String code) [0x00007] in <018e8bf6db3d46cd85eb0a9bc95f4b3f>:0
> at Plugin.LatestVersion.LatestVersionImplementation.GetLatestVersionNumber () [0x001ff] in <7361502664264164a28b556feec777a7>:0
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Plugin.LatestVersion.LatestVersionImplementation.GetLatestVersionNumber () [0x0023d] in <7361502664264164a28b556feec777a7>:0

Comment: have you tried `2.1.1-beta.107` as suggested in the bug report?

Comment: @Jason no, prerelease is not installed, i will try that and update here.

Comment: @Jason I have tried the 2.1.1-beta.107 version now getting another exception. Updated the question with latest findings.

Comment: I would create a new bug, or update the existing one.  Unfortunately the logic used to check the version is very brittle and is just prone to break every time Google changes their webpage layout.

Comment: @Jason Please update here, if you get a solution